# After installation, mouse does not work and desktop does not load

Tags: 16.04, dual-boot

I've encountered a problem using Ubuntu 16.04 I installed alongside Windows.

Ubuntu loads well, but as soon as it reaches the login screen, things start to go wrong. There is a strange loading bar with five dots (dots that keep appearing and disappearing, increasing in number from one to five) that sits in the middle of the screen and looks as if something should be loading.

The cursor doesn't appear. I can only use the up and down arrows to select either the main account (and here I can strangely type my password) or the guest account.

On both accounts I can do nothing, except clicking the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key and either lock or close the account. The screen appears kinda zoomed and the programs on the left bar are all on top of each other. The loading bar still sits happily in the middle of the screen loading god know what, to no no avail...

My only option is therefore to just click <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F3</kbd>, reach a black screen with a console where, supposedly, I should be able to type codes. But here again I can't type anything, therefore I click <kbd>ESC</kbd> and the computer restarts, so I can load Windows and come here to ask for your help.

What can I do to save the Ubuntu install, or at least to access and copy files I saved before reinstalling Ubuntu?

Comment: Boot from a LiveUSB (the Ubuntu install USB). Old or new, it does not matter. Select the "Try Ubuntu" environment. If your mouse and keyboard still don't work, then you have faulty hardware someplace.

Comment: Thanks user535733 I booted from a USB with the latest version of Ubuntu on it and it worked perfectly fine with it. No problems with the mouse or letters. The try ubuntu desktop was fine as well.

Comment: Therefore there must be a problem with my ubuntu partition. Maybe due to a problem caused by a windows

Comment: What makes you believe that Windows has been corrupting or changing settings in your Ubuntu partition?

Comment: I did an upgrade and quite a few updates. Acording to some articles I was reading it would seem that Windows doesn't concern itself with other partitions on a computer and that changes might destabilize other partitions when they exist

Comment: @NBeai some Windows updates can wipe Ubuntu partitions on MBR partitioned disks.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to all the people who helped for your time ! Strangely I solved the problem selecting the "fix the broken packages" option. I was quite unsure whether to use it or not. But it worked well.

*Little update : the systems works fine and I was able to to the update to the last distribution 18.04.1 LTS